# fix tkinter Progressbar with Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, treeview

good evening for all
for a project I have to read and filter a big table (more than 50k lines) using tkinter for this I created a progressbar which is activated while the application calls the filter function in the background.
the problem is that my progress bar does not move i tried with the threading library but nothing changed. does anyone have a solution?
if you also have an idea to insert the lines more quickly in the treeview it would really help me a lot

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from threading import *
import time

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("table manipulation")
        # I create a random table with 50 rows
        self.my_table=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,4))

        #I create a Progressbar
        self.progressbar=ttk.Progressbar(self,orient='horizontal',mode='indeterminate',length=280,value=0)
        self.progressbar.pack(fill=X)

        #I create a single filter for the example
        self.filter_frame = Frame(self)
        self.filter_frame.pack()
        self.create_filter()

        #I create a table with tkinter treeview
        self.table_frame = Frame(self)
        self.table_frame.pack()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.table_frame, show='headings')
        self.create_table()

    def create_filter(self):
        #for example i create one filter
        self.my_filter=ttk.Combobox(self.filter_frame,values=[''] +list(set(self.my_table.values.tolist()[0])) , state="readonly")
        self.my_filter.pack()
        self.my_filter.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.threading)


    def create_table(self):
        self.tree["columns"] =self.my_table.columns.values.tolist()
        self.tree.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=X)
        for i in self.my_table.columns.values.tolist():
            self.tree.column(i, anchor="w")
            self.tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor="w")
        for n in range(len(self.my_table)):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=n, values=self.my_table.values.tolist()[n])

    def filter_function(self,*args):
        for n in self.tree.get_children():
            time.sleep(1) #to check if my progressbar moves
            if self.tree.item(n)['values'][0]!=self.my_filter.get():
                self.tree.delete(n)

    def threading(self,*args):
        self.progressbar.start()
        t1=Thread(target=self.filter_function())
        t1.start()
        self.progressbar.stop()



Application().mainloop()
```

Comment: `target=self.filter_function()` immediate runs `self.filter_function()` and then passes the result to `target`.

Comment: you have imported `tkinter` in three different ways...

Comment: also best to avoid wildcard `*` imports.

Comment: I have already tried to execute the function directly by passing the function to target, it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for those who need it

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("table manipulation")
        # I create a random table with 10 rows
        self.my_table=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))

        #I create a Progressbar
        self.progressbar=ttk.Progressbar(self,orient='horizontal',mode='indeterminate',length=280,value=0)
        self.progressbar.pack()


        

        #I create a single filter for the example
        self.filter_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.filter_frame.pack()
        self.create_filter()

        #I create a table with tkinter treeview
        self.table_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.table_frame.pack()
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.table_frame, show='headings')
        threading.Thread(target=self.create_table() , daemon=True).start()



    def create_filter(self):
        #for example i create one filter
        self.my_filter=ttk.Combobox(self.filter_frame,values=[''] +list(set(self.my_table.values.tolist()[0])) , state="readonly")
        self.my_filter.pack()
        self.my_filter.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.threading)


    def create_table(self):
        self.treeview["columns"] =self.my_table.columns.values.tolist()
        self.treeview.pack()
        for i in self.my_table.columns.values.tolist():
            self.treeview.column(i, anchor="w")
            self.treeview.heading(i, text=i, anchor="w")
        for n in range(len(self.my_table)):
            self.treeview.insert("", "end", text=n, values=self.my_table.values.tolist()[n])
    def test(self):
        for n in range(200):
            time.sleep(1) #to check if my progressbar moves

    def filter_function(self,*args):

        self.progressbar.start()
        for n in self.treeview.get_children():
            time.sleep(1) #to check if my progressbar moves
            if self.treeview.item(n)['values'][0]!=self.my_filter.get():
                self.treeview.delete(n)
        self.progressbar.stop()



    def threading(self,*args):
        threading.Thread(target=self.filter_function , daemon=True).start()




Application().mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the change was?